# How to call a function while unpacking arguments for every single element?

Tags: python, pyqt5

How to call a function on every element that unpacked by unpacking arguments?? let me sample.
I have a string that has unknown number of braces in that. On the other side I have a dictionary that contains same number of/but QLineEdit objects in that. So I want to unpack arguments in the dictionary call a function (text() function) on that and replace the variables (which is going to be string) with braces (string.format()). So the question is how to call a function on that? I want some thing like code below:

```
dict = {1: QLineEditObject}
"I am {}".format(*dict.values().text())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use dict as it is a built-in type. On the other hand going to the problem you must obtain each object using list comprehension:

```
my_dict = {1: QLineEditObject}
print("I am {}".format(*[le.text() for le in my_dict.values()]))
```